# Checking connection status with Domino server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is it is possible to check the connection status with [Domino server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lotus_Domino) using a C# API?

I have a C# application, and I have to check if the connection with the Domino server is still alive or thr Domino server restarts and I lose thr connection. How I can check that programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick.  If this fails then the connection to the server couldn't be made.

```
Domino.NotesSession s = new Domino.NotesSession();
Domino.NotesDatabase db;

try
{
   LNSession.Initialize("password");
   LNDatabase = LNSession.GetDatabase("my lotus mail server", @"names.nsf", false);
}
catch (Exception e)   // Not sure on the specific exception
{
   // Connection failed
}
```